# webstorm 10 chrome extension debugging

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-extension, webstorm

I installed the extension in chrome and the run and debug icons show up in the Webstorm IDE.  I start a debugging session and it opens the page in chrome and live updates occur when I change the HTML.  The debug window also opens in the IDE in webstorm and I can see all of the usual elements of a debug session, except: I can only view the HTML page - I can't view other assets like js files that are loaded via script tags - and I can't set breakpoints in the script in the HTML file, let alone in the other assets and I can't set breakpoints in the editor in the IDE.

Is this working or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best things about debugging with WebStorm is that you put breakpoints in your original files in the editor. Here's an example: https://youtu.be/JnMvok0Yks8?t=10m22s

Comment: Yes, it is quite brilliant.  I managed to get that working so thanks for the video.  Now I have a problem seeing the full object tree in the variables window. Like for example I can only see one child property (`location`) plus `__proto__ ` for the document object... I can't find any setting or other resources to guide me on this, is there something I'm missing?